# Comcast ipv6 test works, works locally, but friend can't connect?

Tags: networking, ipv6

So after finding out about IPv6, I got really excited. Finally, I am free from the hell that is NAT! I went to http://test-ipv6.com/, and was excited to see that I have my very own IPv6 /48 subnet!

ifconfig confirmed I have a global /64 IPv6 subnet. 2^64 addresses all to myself. Oh boy.

I tryed `ping6` on my global address, and it worked. This was cool, but I wanted to see if people outside my LAN could do the same. So I asked my friend, also on Comcast in the same city, to `ping6` me. He got no response.

OK, maybe `icmp6` is firewalled or something. So the next thing I tried is spinning up a webserver with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. I tried connecting to it with `http://[my address]`, and it worked! Great!

He tried visiting the exact same address in his web browser, and it failed! No connection!

What could possibly be going on here? Is Comcast IPv6 support half-baked? I want to be able to bypass the NAT from anywhere!

Comment: You should be thankful it didn’t work. Because if it did, that would mean there’s no IPv6 firewall between you and the Internet.

Comment: Have you checked your router?  Most should have IPv6 incoming connections firewalled by default.

Comment: @heavyd Ah. Makes sense. So when I allow incoming connections, what's the easiest way to set up a firewall so I can just open whatever ports I want open?

Comment: @RenéG, that depends on your router.  Mine has a interface similar to the  IPv4 NAT port forwarding interface to open specific ports.

Comment: @DanielB That is not how IPv6 is supposed to work. Firewalls are supposed to be deployed on endpoints, not on routers/by ISP.

Comment: Firewalls are supposed to be deployed wherever you need them. Network boundaries are a very good choice. IPv4 or IPv6 or whatever doesn’t matter in that regard.